# Python read and store each line of file in a separate variable of your choice without multiple "with open" calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, readfile, with-statement

As mentioned in the Question title, I have below script that reads an  (in the code below `<authfile>` is just a placeholder which can contain any secure auth file like Git) and stores the inner lines as credentials into separate variables of User's choice:

```
import itertools

with open('.<authfile>', 'r') as <authfile>:
    gist_id = next(itertools.islice(<authfile>, 0, None)).rstrip('\n')
with open('.<authfile>', 'r') as <authfile>:
    token = next(itertools.islice(<authfile>, 1, None)).rstrip('\n')
```

But as you see in code, there's bit of non-performance as I have to use 2 `with open` calls for getting separate lines by number and storing into variables.

My sample data file as I try to read looks quite like below, **but the order of gist_ids may change**, token I will keep it at last as much as possible, so you see it's better in my case to read this file just by specific line numbers, still open to suggestions for managing this file:

```
<gist_id1>
<gist_id2>
<gist_id4>
....
....
....
<token>
```

How can I make this a performant script which fires single `with open` call and still stores each line(without newline) into a separate variable? Also how can I do this with minimal code-change ?

Comment: Open the file once, and make two `readline()` calls?

Comment: Sorry, am a newbie in Python, you mean to say, just `with open` once and instead of `next` I need to use `readline` ?

Comment: That would be the normal way.  I've never seen `itertools.islice` used to read a text file.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah it's bit off I agree, but I had to make sure I can get line of my choice by specifying it's number which I did by using `next()` and for that `itertools.islice` was required, can we do this same thing by `readline()` as well, if so how ? Can you show by example or amend your answer for the same ?

Comment: `lines = open("authfile.txt").readlines()` will read the entire file into a Python list.  From there, you can do random addressing to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if my answer here qualifies for minimal code change or not, but I was able to figure out the way to have any specific line to be read from file and store it in separate variables also of my wish.

With inspiration and ideas from Tim Roberts I got it working without using `itertools` module and just adding another method for proper enumeration. Below is my answer:

```
def get_lines(fp, line_numbers):
    return (x for i, x in enumerate(fp) if i in line_numbers)
with open('.<authfile>', 'r') as <authfile>:
    lines = get_lines(<authfile>, [0,1])
    lines = list(lines)
    gist_id = lines[0].rstrip()
    token = lines[1].rstrip()
```

**Note:** I can specify any line to be read by adding it in this array `[0,1]` like `[0,1,5,7,9]`.

Please comment here if anyone needs further explanation of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just fetching the first two lines, you don't need anything more than:

```
with open('.<authfile>', 'r') as authfile:
    gist_id = authfile.readline().rstrip()
    token = authfile.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct, but I am planning to use this same auth file for other gists as well in future, where the GistID would be dfferent which I can store in alternate lines and call it by their line numbers like I did with `next()` method. Can you amend your answer to include a generalized case where I can get any line by specifying it's number and still in one `with open` call only ? Sorry not to have you overworked, but I prefer to use only one auth file as much as possible.

Comment: Relying on line numbers is extremely delicate.  Is there not some keyword you can search for?  You really haven't shown us your incoming data at all.

Comment: Actually initially I try to keep the auth file simple, also I know that in bash and other environments auth and env files are stored in form of key-value pairs where searching by specific keywords comes in handy, but for now I am looking to keep auth file little bit ambiguous to other persons just to ensure only I can decode it. Call it a paranoia !! Also if I use this auth file frequently for gists updation then  imagine the key-value pairs; `gist_id1=<id1> \n gist_id2=<id2>...`, you see how it could become still annoying even with keyword search ?

Comment: updated my question with sample data-file.